# What are the most popular CPU/GPU miners with scrypt-jane support

Tags: gpu-mining, cpu-mining, scrypt

There are a few github projects, but it doesn't look as though there's a 'mainstream' option with good support for varying protocol. Is there any one most popular?

Answer (score 1):

There is a working version of cgminer that supports both scrypt and scryp-jane, available here:

https://sites.google.com/site/rmdavidson/

Comment: This could be more useful as a comment.